# MVC4 Simple Membership Provider setup

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to use mvc4 Simple membership provider. So I set up a new MVC4 internet application. Click Debug and I see that db and tables were created for me.

[image]

Is this all I need to do?. 
Some articles:
http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx

http://blog.longle.net/2012/09/25/seeding-users-and-roles-with-mvc4-simplemembershipprovider-simpleroleprovider-ef5-codefirst-and-custom-user-properties/

tell me to add

```
<membership defaultProvider >...
```

section. is this necessary?

Also:
I can't get ASP.Net configuration tool to work. It says "An error was encountered. Please return to the previous page and try again. "

??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you created a new MVC 4 web application using the Internet template it should have wired up SimpleMembership for a basic log-on/log-off functionality.  It should have already updated your web.config with the proper settings.  It should have setup the membership and roles and they should looks something like this.

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SimpleRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="SimpleRoleProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider, WebMatrix.WebData"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<membership defaultProvider="SimpleMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="SimpleMembershipProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

SimpleMembership does not use the ASP.NET Configuration Tool used with the traditional ASP.NET membership.  You have to create your own web pages for managing roles and users.

The Internet template just creates the basic functionality for authentication and authorization in your application. But SimpleMembership is very extensible. For example it is fairly easy to [customize what type of information you want to capture in the user profile](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/01/seeding-customizing-aspnet-mvc.html) or [setup email confirmation of new users](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/02/adding-email-confirmation-to.html).